# how to group by parent array in foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

How can i achieve this  results. I want to group the data by b_id so this is my attempt
but i can't figure it out instead its keeping displaying an ungroup data.
below i have list the code and the result what i want and i don't want.

Test Data

```
$d = "[
       {
          \"b_id\": 1,
          \"d\": 0,
          \"lo\": 10,
          \"m\": 4000,
          \"pts\": [
             {
                \"amount\": 3500,
                \"b_id\": 1,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 2,
                \"user_id\": 27
             },
             {
                \"amount\": 3000,
                \"b_id\": 1,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 1,
                \"user_id\": 27
             },
             {
                \"amount\": 2000,
                \"b_id\": 1,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 2,
                \"user_id\": 20
             },
             {
                \"amount\": 1000,
                \"b_id\": 1,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 1,
                \"user_id\": 20
             }
          ],
          \"ro\": 10,
          \"side\": 2,
          \"user_id\": 27,
          \"w\": 5000
       },
       {
          \"b_id\": 2,
          \"d\": 0,
          \"lo\": 10,
          \"m\": 6000,
          \"pts\": [
             {
                \"amount\": 4000,
                \"b_id\": 2,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 1,
                \"user_id\": 27
             },
             {
                \"amount\": 2000,
                \"b_id\": 2,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 2,
                \"user_id\": 27
             },
             {
                \"amount\": 1000,
                \"b_id\": 2,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 2,
                \"user_id\": 20
             },
             {
                \"amount\": 2000,
                \"b_id\": 2,
                \"fid\": 2,
                \"side\": 1,
                \"user_id\": 20
             }
          ],
          \"ro\": 9,
          \"side\": 1,
          \"user_id\": 27,
          \"w\": 3000
       }
    ]";
```

Code

```
    $d = json_decode($d);
    foreach($d as $data => $row) {
        foreach($row as $a => $b) {
            if($a == "pts") {
                foreach($b as $col => $val) {
                    echo "======[START (b_id: ".$row->b_id."]======<br>";
                    $odds = getOdds($row->m,$row->lo,$row->ro);
                    $ret = getMax($val->amount,$odds);
                    $amount = round(abs($val->amount - $ret),2);

                    echo "Odds: $odds<br>";
                    echo "Ret: $ret<br>";
                    echo "Amount: $amount <br>";
                    echo "=======[END (b_id: ".$row->b_id."]=======<br><br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }


    function getOdds($bets,$a,$b) {
       return ($bets * $b) / $a;
    }

    function getMax($bet, $max) {
        global $bets;
        $ret = 0;

        if($bets < $max) {
            $bets += $bet;
            $ret = ($bets % $max);

            if($ret == $bets)
                $ret = 0;
        } else
            $ret = $bet;

        return $ret;
    }
```

results

```
        ======[START (b_id: 1]======
        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 0
        Amount: 3500
        =======[END (b_id: 1]=======

        ======[START (b_id: 1]======
        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 2500
        Amount: 500
        =======[END (b_id: 1]=======

        ======[START (b_id: 1]======
        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 2000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 1]=======

        ======[START (b_id: 1]======
        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 1000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 1]=======

        ======[START (b_id: 2]======
        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 4000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 2]=======

        ======[START (b_id: 2]======
        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 2000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 2]=======

        ======[START (b_id: 2]======
        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 1000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 2]=======

        ======[START (b_id: 2]======
        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 2000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 2]=======
```

But i want this results

```
       ======[START (b_id: 1]======
        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 0
        Amount: 3500

        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 2500
        Amount: 500

        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 2000
        Amount: 0

        Odds: 4000
        Ret: 1000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 1]=======


        ======[START (b_id: 2]======
        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 4000
        Amount: 0

        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 2000
        Amount: 0

        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 1000
        Amount: 0

        Odds: 5400
        Ret: 2000
        Amount: 0
        =======[END (b_id: 2]=======
```

Is possible to achieve this kind of results in foreach?
thank you

Comment: What you want to implement is called a _control break_.

Answer (score 1):

The grouping is possible and only require a small change to your code.

Note that the printing of the START and END lines moved outside of the foreach and just into the "if($a == "pts") {" and that an extra "
" was added to the print of the Amount line.

```
if($a == "pts") {
    echo "======[START (b_id: ".$row->b_id."]======<br>";
    foreach($b as $col => $val) {
        $odds = getOdds($row->m,$row->lo,$row->ro);
        $ret = getMax($val->amount,$odds);
        $amount = round(abs($val->amount - $ret),2);

        echo "Odds: $odds<br>";
        echo "Ret: $ret<br>";
        echo "Amount: $amount <br><br>";
    }
    echo "=======[END (b_id: ".$row->b_id."]=======<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be scripted a number of ways, but some important points are:

- Don't ask php to perform the same calculation in an inner loop when it can be performed just once in the outer loop.
- I like to keep the processing and the displaying code component separated as much as possible, so the inner loop's data is collected, glued & pushed into the outer loop's collections array, then when finished iterating, glue the collections data together.  This also prevents any trailing/dangling markup (`<br>`) tags.
- You can afford to omit the if condition in your nested loops and one of the loops can be removed entirely.  Use `array_column()` to isolate the `$amount` data because that is the only data that you actually work with.
- Don't use `global` declarations when you can pass a given value as a parameter to a function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tsHma))

```
$break = "\n"; // <br>
$break2 = "\n\n";  // <br><br>

$collections = [];
foreach($d as $row) {
    $odds = getOdds($row->m, $row->lo, $row->ro);
    $collection = [];
    foreach(array_column($row->pts, 'amount') as $amount) {
        $ret = getMax($row->m, $amount, $odds);              // I am assuming that $row-m is supposed to be $bets
        $amount = round(abs($amount - $ret), 2);
        $collection[] = implode($break, ["Odds: {$odds}", "Ret: {$ret}", "Amount: {$amount}"]);
    }
    $collections[] = implode($break, [
        "======[START (b_id: {$row->b_id}]======",
        implode($break2, $collection),
        "=======[END (b_id: {$row->b_id}]=======",
    ]);
}
echo implode($break2, $collections);
```

Output:

```
======[START (b_id: 1]======
Odds: 4000
Ret: 3500
Amount: 0

Odds: 4000
Ret: 3000
Amount: 0

Odds: 4000
Ret: 2000
Amount: 0

Odds: 4000
Ret: 1000
Amount: 0
=======[END (b_id: 1]=======

======[START (b_id: 2]======
Odds: 5400
Ret: 4000
Amount: 0

Odds: 5400
Ret: 2000
Amount: 0

Odds: 5400
Ret: 1000
Amount: 0

Odds: 5400
Ret: 2000
Amount: 0
=======[END (b_id: 2]=======
```